# Use Google Maps without external calls on Facebook playable ads

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

A developer in my team has created an HTML5 demo version of a native app, so that we can use it on Facebook as a "playable ad". This is usually done with games, so that gaming companies build an HTML5 demo version of the game with one level that you can play directly on Facebook before downloading the app from the app stores.

The thing is, our demo version has to use a Google Maps map, to pick different markers on the screen. The demo works on a browser, but it does not load the map when uploaded to Facebook Ads Manager. I guess it's because we're supposed to not make external calls, but to keep everything within the HTML5 file.

**Do you see any option to load Google Maps without having to load the live JS file from Google?** In other words, **can we migrate somehow the map functionality to the HTML file to avoid external calls?**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use google maps in facebook playable ads, here you can find the specification https://www.facebook.com/business/help/412951382532338?ref=FBB_PlayableAds

The thing you can do is to use a fake google map, for example an image or some animations that represent actual in-app behavior but in fact dont use real google maps.